# If I want an asynchronous thread to, do I need setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

UPDATE:
The problem I am having stems from something entirely different, I would delete the question alltogether but since there are answers, I am not allowed to.
/OP

I have a script that is very complex and hard to distill, but here is the essence of what I am doing:

```
var modulesCount = 4;

// setup the modules object
for (var i = 1; i <= modulesCount; i++) {     
   composeModule(i);
}
```

I have some strange behaviour, where is seems every call to the function `composeModule()` isn't made, so I figured, will I have to use a `setTimeout` in order to split the thread into say 4 different threads like this? Say like this:

```
// setup the modules object
for (var i = 1; i <= modulesCount; i++) {     
   setTimeout(function() {
       composeModule(i);
   }, 1);
}
```

------------------- UPDATE

Tried this

```
    var c = 1;
    for (var i=1;i<=modulesCount;i++) {     
       console.error('actual count is: '+c+' while variable i is: '+i);
       self.composeModule(i,initialCall);
       c++;
    }
```

to check if there is a problem with my variable i but it is identic to c in every console output. Or did I misunderstand you guys'es point entirely?

Comment: JavaScript isn't really a multithread capable language

Comment: Why do you think all the function calls aren't being made, and why would sprinkling in `setTimeout` calls fix it? I'm not following at all.

Comment: Can you use `console.log` or **https://github.com/flatiron/winston** to log some messages in your code?  I have a hard time believing the loop will not call `composeModule` 4 times.  Maybe your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Please put a `console.log` inside `composeModule` and also share that source if you can.

Comment: you're right, my problem lies elsewhere, it does get called 4 times like intended. So should I delete this question? I also have 3 votes to close so I will just go ahead and delete it all together.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to write that loop, you need to put the variable `i` into a closure:

```
// setup the modules object
for (var i = 1; i <= modulesCount; i++) {     
   (function (inner_i) {setTimeout(function() {
       composeModule(inner_i);
   }})(i), 1);
}
```

See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: You get a +1 for figuring out what OP actually needed and not what he asked for. I'm voting as duplicate :)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think the OP only added the setTimeout to try to debug the issue.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

To split threads in javascript there is a new function called web worker. A worker is, as a rule of thumb, something similar to a Thread in Java.

Refer to the following to gain more insight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers